# Automatic probability densities

Tags: probability, automatic-differentiation

I have found automatic differentiation to be extremely useful when writing mathematical software. I now have to work with random variables and functions of the random variables, and it seems to me that an approach similar to automatic differentiation could be used for this, too.

The idea is to start with a basic random vector with given multivariate distribution and then you want to work with the implied probability distributions of functions of components of the random vector. The idea is to define operators that automatically combine two probability distributions appropriately when you add, multiply, divide two random variables and transform the distribution appropriately when you apply scalar functions such as exponentiation. You could then combine these to build any function you need of the original random variables and automatically have the corresponding probability distribution available.

Does this sound feasible? If not, why not? If so and since it's not a particularly original thought, could someone point me to an existing implementation, preferably in C

Answer (score 0):

There has been a lot of work on probabilistic programming. One issue is that as your distribution gets more complicated you start needing more complex techniques to sample from it.

There are a number of ways this is done. Probabilistic graphical models gives one vocabulary for expressing these models, and you can then sample from them using various Metropolis-Hastings-style methods. [Here is a crash course](http://web.mit.edu/~wingated/www/introductions/mcmc-gibbs-intro.pdf).

Another model is Probabilistic Programming, which can be done through an embedded domain specific language, directly. Oleg Kiselyov's [HANSEI](http://okmij.org/ftp/kakuritu/index.html) is an example of this approach. Once they have the program they can inspect the tree of decisions and expand them out by a form of importance sampling to gain the most information possible at each step.

You may also want to read ["Nonstandard Interpretations of Probabilistic
Programs for Efﬁcient Inference"](http://web.mit.edu/wingated/www/papers/opover.pdf) by Wingate et al. which describes one way to use extra information about the derivative of your distribution to accelerate Metropolis-Hastings-style sampling techniques. I personally use automatic differentiation to calculate those derivatives and this brings the topic back to automatic-differentiation. ;)